# Access URL fragment in Lambda Node.js function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, url, aws-lambda

I have an S3 website that I'm trying to password-protect using a Lambda function and CloudFront. When a user tries to access the site, the Lambda function will redirect them to my Cognito login page, then redirect back to the site with a token.

When redirecting back, the access token is in the fragment (after "#"). Is it possible to obtain this token in the Lambda function using Node.js?

Answer (score 3):

No, it isn't.  The fragment is only available to JS running on the browser -- it's never sent to any web server.

There's an example [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/authorization-lambda-at-edge/blob/master/www/index.html) of one way to get it, as mentioned in [Authorization@Edge – How to Use Lambda@Edge and JSON Web Tokens to Enhance Web Application Security](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/authorizationedge-how-to-use-lambdaedge-and-json-web-tokens-to-enhance-web-application-security/), which uses Lambda@Edge rather than API Gateway (the two services have some overlapping functionality).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Oh yeah I saw this as well, but it seems to use a separate index.html to parse out the fragment before it goes to the Lambda function. So there's no way to just do it in the Lambda function itself?

Comment: Specifically, the line of code that grabs it is: https://github.com/aws-samples/authorization-lambda-at-edge/blob/master/www/index.html#L34 @ `var results = new RegExp('[\?&#]access_token=([^&#]*)').exec(location.href);`